# Trouble signing in as admin account after change of Apple ID email address

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, apple-id, user-account, administrator

I had to move to another mail provider therefore I changed my Apple ID.

Unfortunately a while ago I've linked my admin account on my MacBook Air with my Apple ID. Now my account is still stuck with the old email address and I can't login as admin to make changes, delete apps or change system prefs.

Luckily I still can sign in after booting the Mac but only after trying it multiple times and switching to sleep mode (some kind of weird auth bug). It looks like that the same problem occurs on all my devices as well but for now I really like to get my mac back to work properly.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: You didn't need to change your Apple ID, btw; you could have just changed the primary email address associated with it. The ID itself doesn't have to be a valid address, nor even actually an email address at all.

Comment: @IsgerJanson Hmm you probably wanted to ping Tetsujin.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Tetsujin! I've changed it back and added the other email to the "reachable at" section. If this all it takes to get the system back to normal I'm fine although I don't get why it's even happening.

Comment: Wish you luck… :)